# How can I remove the pesky "The runCommand action was canceled" dialog box after a "cancel = true" statement

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba

On the Form_beforeupdate() event of my form "Alias" I have this...

```
If IsNull(Me.txtFName) And IsNull(Me.txtLName) Then
MsgBox "You must enter a contact!", vbokayonly, "Contact"
Cancel = True
End If
```

Anytime this cancels a runCommand code such as...

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

a dialog appears telling me that it was canceled. Is there a way to suppress those dialogs?

Comment: @hansup The Docmd.runCommand... is located on many different controls and they all surrounded with a    if(Me.Dirty) then...end if. Also doing the Option Explicit still produced the same results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an error handler to trap and ignore error 2501, which is triggered when the form's *Before Update* event cancels `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`

The following example is from my form which has a command button to save the current record.  It suppresses that *"RunCommand action was canceled"* message as I think you wish.

Since your form's code apparently calls `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` from multiple locations, replace each of those calls with `SaveRecord` as I did in *cmdSave_Click()*.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit ' <-- NEVER troubleshoot VBA code without this!!!

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    SaveRecord
End Sub

Private Sub SaveRecord()
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

ExitHere:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 2501 ' The RunCommand action was canceled.
        ' do nothing --> just ignore the error
    Case Else
        ' notify user about any other error
        strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
            & ") in procedure SaveRecord"
        MsgBox strMsg
    End Select
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(Me.txtBlock_start.Value) Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a start time!", vbOKOnly, "Start Time"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds good i'll try it. Just one more question. Sometimes it throws an error in other cases not only DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord. How can I determine the Err.Number for other errs to put in the Select Case  to ignore?

Comment: wow that feels like a duh moment ;) Thanks you have been lots of help!

Comment: So I just finally got around to implement this and it work great, the error was ignored. Seemly the Cancel = True was ignored as well. Everything I may have placed after the SaveRecord call in the cmdSave_Click() was still executed. This wasn't a behavior I wanted.  So instead of putting the error handler in the SaveRecord() sub, I tried putting it at the end of cmdSave_Click() sub and it worked perfect.

Comment: I believe this is what is happening. Please correct me if I am wrong. I start the process by clicking on a button attached to cmdSave_click(). The form stops the procedure before it saves, cancels the save process if it needs to, not the entire cmdSave_click(). Since the error handling is processed and resumed in a different sub (no error passes through, right?) any Open form actions continue on. These action are not updates so they will not be canceled by the Cancel = true of the form_beforeupdate.

Comment: Ah, you have other stuff going on in `cmdSave_click()` ... more than just `SaveRecord()`.  Then, yes, those other things would still happen.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this on a 'Save and Open the Receipts form' button.

```
Private Sub btnSaveOpenReceipts_Click()

'''''SaveRecord'''''
If (Me.Dirty) Then
    SaveRecord
End If

'''''OpenReciepts'''''
If (Me.Dirty) Then 'unsure it saved
Exit Sub
Else
'blah blah blah
End If
End Sub
```